# Is there an inyan to eat Cheesecake on Shavuos?

Tags: minhag, food, shavuos, dairy

I know everybody does it, and I know there is [an *inyan* to eat dairy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7875/759), but is there an *inyan* specifically for eating cheesecake on *Shavuos*? And if so, where does it come from?

Comment: The general question is found here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7875/759

Comment: You answered your own question: there is an inyan to eat cheesecake because everyone does it and they don't know why. That's what an inyan is!

Comment: Ha, although I am not satisfied with that really :)

Comment: Alright, so my semantics were wrong. I've heard it reffered to as a minhag by many a Rabbi.

Comment: Its minhag to have dairy on shavuos. Minhag found in rema and a lot of places. Many given reasons for the minhag are given.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know about cheesecake specifically.

Comment: Maybe cheesecake became popular on Shavuot because people wanted to make a Mezonot after they made Kiddush, so they could have Kiddush Bimkom Seuda. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16556/603

Comment: [Among the reasons](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7878) for eating dairy is a reason to eat cheese specifically, which is a partial answer, I suppose.

Comment: Point of order: [Not everybody does it.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28742/is-there-an-inyan-to-eat-cheesecake-on-shavuos/28750#comment70072_28750)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Nitei Gavriel Shavuos 29:1 note 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46443&st=&pgnum=170&hilite=) mentions from Kovetz Bais Talmud that in the times of the second Bais HaMikdash they used to eat on Shavuos (לפתות מלחם ומלח (חלב. This sounds a bit like cheesecake to me.

Comment: How does he know this? What's the source?

Comment: Rabbi Tzinner made a mistake. He cites Beit Talmud 1882, but it's actually Beit Talmud 1881, [p. 87](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48109&st=&pgnum=96&hilite=) where there's a reference to a testimony by Philo who stated that the Essenes would not eat meat or drink wine during Shavuot but would instead eat bread and salt ([link](http://www.earlyjewishwritings.com/text/philo/book34.html#:~:text=And%20when%20each,with%20anything%20else%2C)). Rabbi Tzinner amends the salt to milk, but I don't know what he based the emendation on.

Answer (score 1):

No. Cheesecake is just delicious.

Comment: What is your source or reasoning for the claim that there's no source for eating cheesecake specifically?

Comment: I'm going to take the admittedly unpopular but unfortunately true position that cheesecake is not delicious.

Comment: My source of reasoning is that while eating dairy is a popular inyan, cheesecake is just a popular choice (especially in America). I personally know many Jews (mostly foreigners) who have never had cheesecake but keep that inyan to eat cheesecake. I'd consider it more of an inyan just to eat cheesecake itself than to eat cheesecake on Shauvos.

Comment: What is your source that cheesecake is delicious?

Comment: @DoubleAA, you've never had my father's cheesecake

Answer (score 1):

[Rabbi Zev Cohen](https://www.adasyeshurun.com/our-rabbi.html) of Chicago writes in [Safa Berurah Shavuos](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/1739742/free-download-easy-online-guide-halachos-of-shavuos.html) (p. 28)

> After staying up all night, we have two fundamental lessons to
> remember. one is to realize that we have achieved great closeness to
> Hashem, and the other is to remember that through receiving the Torah
> we now have the tools to meet all the challenges of the yetzer hara.
> To accomplish both of these goals at once, we eat a food item that is
> both milchigs and chametz. We eat chametz to symbolize that after a
> whole night of learning Torah we are now empowered to fight the yetzer
> hara represented by that chametz, and we also eat milchigs in it to
> symbolize the concept of the shiva nekiim and dam neechar v’naaseh
> chalav that brought us so close to Hashem, like the closness of a of a
> chassan and kallah. Cheesecake (or even better, a cheese danish) is the
> perfect food to accomplish both messages.

Comment: This could also be done with a cheese sandwich or pizza

Answer (score 0):

B"H

I heard in a shiur that in fact the entire source for eating dairy in general on Shavuos is just because there's an inyan to eat specifically cheesecake on Shavuos.

The shiur quoted a Ramah (don't rememeber source, around laws of Shavuos in Orach Chayim) that on every Yom Tov, we usually make a Zeicher for something

(Sukkos, Pesach - Matzah etc.)

but what's the Zeicher for Shavuos?

The answer is that we should make a Zeicher for the 2 breads that were offered on the alter for Shavuos.

On yom Tov usually one only eats one meal of bread by day (unlike Shaboos), but the Ramah says there that in order to make a proper Zeicher for the 2 breads, one should eat 2 "bread" meals on Shavuos.

Since in general one eats two meals per day, one dairy and one meat, therefore, he writes, that the first meal should be bread "mixed with cheese" (AKA, cheesecake), and then one should wait a while and have the second meal with meat.

So, according to the shiur, based on that the proper thing to do is to make kiddush (after shacharis/mussaf), then have cheese cake as the meal. Then wait an hour and start the meat meal.

Comment: The Rema is here: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.494.3?lang=bi He doesn't say anything about eating "bread mixed with cheese", just that one eats dairy food followed by meat, which necessitates using two separate loaves of bread.

Comment: The Magen Avraham there mentions that the custom is to bake the first loaf of bread with butter (still doesn't sound like cheesecake to me). Also note that this is all happening within the same meal, no need to bench between the dairy and meat and no need to wait an hour.

Comment: @JoelK one must always say an after bracha when when finishing meat/dairy to then eat the opposite and one must do this regardless of the time one waits in between whether the bracha is at the beginning of the time to wait or at the end. I don't have the siman right now but this is clear in yore dea. As for the hour time. Waiting a full hour is based on the Zohar. Not everyone does this or agrees that's the p'shat there

Comment: @Dude Just look at OC 494:3 (link above) with Mishnah Berurah. No need for bracha acharona if going from milk to meat (unless one eats hard cheese)

Comment: @JoelK that doesn't say what you are claiming it says. It is only addressing eating a dairy meal and a meat meal and does not say anything in regards to whether one needs to wait or say a bracha in between. For that you need yore dea not orech chaim

Comment: @Dude MB 494:16 ויזהר ליקח מפה אחרת כשרוצה לאכול בשר. **וא"צ להפסיק בבהמ"ז אם אינו אוכל גבינה קשה** אלא יקנח פיו יפה וידיח כדאיתא ביו"ד סי' פ"ט:

Comment: I looked up the siman again yore dea (89) and I was wrong. There it only addresses bentching from going from meat to milk. Though for those that hold one should wait after dairy even though m'ikar hadin that isn't necessary then if waiting is involved for that minhag a bracha achrona makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding was that originally eating cheesecake on Shavuos was a regional custom in Central Europe (IE Germany and Hungary) and Eastern European Jews tended to view blintzes as the de facto Shavuos food. Cheesecake just became more popular in the U.S.

Comment: true; in Iraq the shavuoth-tradition was to eat 'kahi', a type of fried puff pastry, which was filled or topped with 'qeymar', a clotted cream made from buffalo milk.